# Is it wrong to put the ViewModel in codebehind?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, code-behind

In MVVM, we normally have a View (XAML + usually empty codebehind) as well as a ViewModel that is a separate class. Interaction between View and ViewModel takes place via data binding.

Assuming the View is just XAML and its codebehind is empty (which is usually the case), is there anything wrong with using the codebehind itself as the ViewModel and binding the View to properties of the codebehind? The separation of concerns is still there - you have a pure XAML view and a ViewModel which is the codebehind, and they communicate with each other only via data binding. The ViewModel can still be unit-tested.

This may sound like heresy, but I can't think of any use cases that would justify having to create separate classes for the ViewModel when the codebehind is in fact empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of code-behind is code that is associated with the view. In XAML, this is usually done via the `x:Class` attribute on the XAML root element, inheriting from the base type of the root element (this is always specified in auto-generated partial class files), and so on. There's actually [a little section in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970568.aspx) that outlines the concept of code-behind in WPF XAML. Since the `x:Class` attribute only lets you specify one class, this basically ties your XAML markup to exactly one class. That class represents its code-behind.

Since code-behind is essentially *view logic*, or the underlying code *for* the XAML markup, you cannot make a code-behind class a view model. View models are completely view-agnostic except for the fact that they provide data to and receive data from their associated views through data binding; code-behind or UI logic on the other hand is primarily concerned with providing behavior to view objects represented by the XAML, and not application logic.

Like others have said, if you can somehow make it work then it's not "wrong" as far as the compiler is concerned, but I would say that's kind of going against the nature of code-behind.

Comment: You originally had a part about using the same viewmodel from multiple views, and that was spot on. You seem to have removed it, but I'll accept your answer if you add it back.

Comment: @Gigi: I don't recall, but I've added a statement about it now.

Comment: I was compelled to revisit this consideration given my current work with Prism+Unity for Xamarin Forms, which offers automatic binding to ViewModel by View naming convention... not disagreeing with points of current or later answers, yet "code behind" could also be looked at as simply the .cs file, which can contain any number of classes... therefore, it seems fine? to go ahead and include the ViewModel class definition in the View.cs file, which could still be hot swapped or otherwise referenced by other views... of course maybe harder to locate visually at a glance but readily with search.

Answer (score 4):

If it works, it isn't *wrong*.

However, MVVM is a pattern and patterns are there for a reason. We put view models in separate classes to enforce MVVM's key principle - separation of concerns(SoC). SoC has a *cultural impact* on your development - you and your team are less likely to get the two mixed up.

Contrary to the statement in your question, you are not allowing separation.

**Here is a use case for you:** By putting the view model in code behind, you are no longer able to hot-swap the view that is used to represent your view model and you *will* find this restrictive.

It is worth remembering that all patterns are tools. They are a means, not an end and you should not break your back to use them. There is wiggle room but in this case, I feel you are wiggling too far.

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter) ViewModels are created specifically for a View, even though they're not tightly integrated together. So how and why would you hot-swap them?

Comment: @Gigi ill use an example from my current project. I have a list of VMs. Each VM has a duration (Timespan). Boss wants two view modes, a listview, and a timeline(custom control). Both views need the same data, but now i can use 2 views on the same view model, even at the same time.

Comment: ViewModels are *not* created specifically for a View. You can have multiple Views over the same ViewModel, something facilitated (even encouraged) by MVVM frameworks like Caliburn.Micro and MVVM Light. A ViewModel should never be tied to its view, much less *be* the view. A code-behind on the other hand *is* the view. So saying you can use a code-behind as a ViewModel is definitely wrong and not a mere cultural concept. While you can databind to code-behind properties, that doesn't mean you get a ViewModel out of it.

Comment: If we said MVC instead of MVVM (same pattern family), would you ever say you can use a View's code as a controller?

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for clarifying my misconception.

Comment: Upvote. Because, if it works, it's probably not wrong. WPF and the .NET runtime will work and run the code. And, yes, there are going to be circumstances where you can combine View and Controller into one class in MVC, if either of them are trivially simple. These are architecture models, not straightjackets.